# How to react on failed transaction (Django)

Tags: python, django, transactions

How to react on failed Django transaction? For example return some kind of error page or reload the page etc.

There is `with transaction.atomic()` in the code so in case that user has been saved but the problem occured during saving userprofile, everything will be rolled back.

But how to detect and react on situations, when transaction failed so it was rolled back?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if register_as_translator_form.is_valid():
            cleaned = register_as_translator_form.cleaned_data

            with transaction.atomic():
                request.user.first_name = cleaned['first_name']
                request.user.last_name = cleaned['last_name']
                request.user.userprofile.IBAN = cleaned['IBAN']
                languages = cleaned['languages']
                language_levels = get_or_create_unknown_language_levels(languages)
                request.user.userprofile.language_levels.add(*language_levels)
                request.user.save()
                request.user.userprofile.is_translator = True
                request.user.userprofile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register-translator-success')
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/) covers this in some detail. If the transaction is rolled back, an exception will be raised and it is up to you to catch it and decide what to do. As for what the appropriate action is, surely this depends on your application?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception (except-try) and return an error message/page.

```
   try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            request.user.first_name = cleaned['first_name']
            request.user.last_name = cleaned['last_name']
            request.user.userprofile.IBAN = cleaned['IBAN']
            languages = cleaned['languages']
            language_levels = get_or_create_unknown_language_levels(languages)
            request.user.userprofile.language_levels.add(*language_levels)
            request.user.save()
            request.user.userprofile.is_translator = True
            request.user.userprofile.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register-translator-success')
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register-translator-failure')
```